# SVN - remote locations

Tags: centos, svn, nautilus, remote

im not sure this is the best place to ask this question, but i'm sure you will have insight..

I am using Ubuntu 11 and RabbitVCS for managing my SVN files. I really like the seamless integration to the file browser.

I have a number of different locations and servers as remote locations within Nautilus (such as SFTP), however RabbitSVN does not show these under as under version control. I've done some research on the subject and it appears this is an intende feature..

So my question.. Is there an alternative bit of software or a plugin to RabbitVCS that will allow the default file browser to work with remote locations?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried sshfs? It allows you to mount remote directories at the system level, so it's lower level than application (Nautilus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using NFS to mount the remote file system, worked a treat allowing the svn meta data through to the file explorer.